# How to update a mongodb collection using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a mongo server having a collection states. whenever a new state is adding it is save in my server. But when i try to edit the collection in front end it is saved as another new collection in my server with different id. how to overcome this.

```
     public  static void CreateData(string pass ,string pass1)
      {

          string StateCode = pass;
          string stateName = pass1;
          insertState(StateCode, stateName);

      }



      private static void insertState(string StateCode, string stateName)
      {
        MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(ConnectionString);
        MongoDatabase myCompany = server.GetDatabase("BackOffice");

        MongoCollection<BsonDocument> tblStates = myCompany.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("tblStates");
        BsonDocument deptartment = new BsonDocument {
                    { "State_strCode", StateCode },
                    { "State_strName", stateName },
                    {"States_strIsActive","Y"},
                    {"State_strFedExStateCode",""},
                    {"State_dtmTimeStamp",DateTime.Now}
                    };
        tblStates.Insert(deptartment);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better define a structure or set a PK:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    [MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes.BsonId]
    public string idCol { get; set; }
}
```

and update your object like this

```
 public void Update(Customer cus)
    {
        if (cus != null)
        {
            MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient client = new MongoClient(_connectionString);
            MongoDatabase db = client.GetServer().GetDatabase(_dbName);
            db.GetCollection(_dbName).Save(cus);
        }

    }
```

Comment: That's right. Here is the documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/

Comment: MongoCollection<BsonDocument> tblGenre =             m       ydb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("tblGenre"); ;
            var query = new QueryDocument {
           { "Genre_strCode", GenerCode }
                   };

            var update = new UpdateDocument {
   { "$set", new BsonDocument("Genre_strName", GenerName) }
         };
            tblGenre.Update(query, update);